# How to install library dependencies as a .tar.gz/.tar.xz archive on Travis CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, tar

I'm using [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci) to compile my program that uses [sdl-2](/questions/tagged/sdl-2). The only problem is, I don't know how to actually install the packages `libsdl2` and `libsdl2-ttf` through [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci).

Here's my config file:

```
language: cpp
compiler: g++
before_script:
  - mkdir -p build
script: make all
install:
  - wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsdl2/libsdl2_2.0.4+dfsg2.orig.tar.gz
  - sudo tar -xzvf libsdl2_2.0.4+dfsg2.orig.tar.gz
  - wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsdl2-ttf/libsdl2-ttf_2.0.12+dfsg1.orig.tar.xz
  - sudo tar xf libsdl2-ttf_2.0.12+dfsg1.orig.tar.xz
```

When the configuration is complete, it can't compile my program since it can't find `SDL2/SDL.h` which is in the `libsdl2` package.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngryLawyer/rust-sdl2/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jamek for giving me a look at [AngryLawyer's own configuration file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AngryLawyer/rust-sdl2/master/.travis.yml). These are the steps:

If the package is archived as `.tar.gz`:

```
install:
- wget [package url]
- tar xzf [package name].tar.gz
- pushd [package name] && ./configure && make && sudo make install && popd
```

If the package is archived as `.tar.xz`:

```
install:
- wget [package url].tar.xz
- tar xf [package name].tar.xz
- pushd [package name] && ./configure && make && sudo make install && popd
```

---

Here's my own configuration file:

```
language: cpp
compiler: gcc
before_script:
  - mkdir -p build
script: make all
before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
install:
  - wget https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.5.tar.gz -O sdl2.tar.gz
  - tar xzf sdl2.tar.gz
  - pushd SDL2-* && ./configure && make && sudo make install && popd
  - wget -q https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
  - tar xzf SDL2_ttf-*.tar.gz
  - pushd SDL2_ttf-* && ./configure && make && sudo make install && popd
  - sudo apt-get install -qq g++-6
  - sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 90
```